# SmartCards in Windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, smartcard

I'm using [ACOS3X](http://acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=images&id=ACOS3X) smart cards in my Delphi application for user authentication. Everything is fine in Windows XP, but in Windows 7, every time I put the card into the reader (which is ACR38-CCID), windows tries to install a driver for it, to no avail. This does not affect my application in any way, but it's really annoying. Should I write a driver for my card just to satisfy Windows 7? And, if yes, could someone please tell me if it's possible to create drivers with Delphi?

Comment: You should contact whoever supplied the card to ask for advice as to why it behaves this way. I'm sure you should not be writing a driver for this card. How could you? You didn't make it. Can you create drivers with Delphi? No you cannot.

Comment: I'm confused that Windows XP doesn't require a driver, while 7 does. Wasn't this always the opposite? And, I can still access the card in 7 using Smart Card API, which shouldn't be possible without a driver. Right?

Comment: Contact the vendor and ask them.

Comment: You can tell windows 7 not to keep updating driver, if you want it that way, look here (http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/disable-windows-update-device-driver-search-prompt/)

Comment: Another setting in registry is [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DriverSearching]
"SearchOrderConfig", with value:
0 --> disable Windows update drivers search
1 --> always do Windows update drivers search
2 --> Search Windows update only if drivers are not installed in the driverstore

Comment: And this is the link to how different windows versions behave regarding drivers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553973(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Well, thanks for all the comments, but I don't want to modify my user's computer. I just want to tell Windows to ignore this specific device. Is there something like a _null_ driver that does nothing but shutting up Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Windows 7 (and IIRC also Vista) does. If you insert a smart card, it tries to locate a minidriver through Windows Update.

Not sure if it works, but you can maybe modify Windows registry to include the necessary entry for your card (but not point to a working implementation).

Look into Windows Minidriver Specification (available from MS) and the "discovery" section in that document.

Comment: The vendor provided me with a quick registry fix. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calis\SmartCards